# A description for this result is not available because of this site's robots.txt - Wordpress site

Tags: php, wordpress, web-crawler, robots.txt

I have a blog at [snowtoseas.com](http://snowtoseas.com). When I google my site, this appears in the description: A description for this result is not available because of this site's robots.txt.

I host with biz.nf and have installed wordpress.org. I've found out that wordpress.org usually creates a virtual robots.txt file that you cannot edit. To get around this, I installed the Virtual Robots.txt to modify the file.

Currently, this is my robots.txt: http://snowtoseas.com/robots.txt

Is it ok? Should I change it to something else or should I install a different plugin?

It's been like this for over a week now, and the description still hasn't changed. I've also searched the site on alternative search engines like DuckDuckGo and the description is still blocked.

When I try to ping Google through the xml-sitemap plugin wordpress offers, it fails and I get this message: *WP HTTP API Web Request failed: cURL error 7: Failed to connect to....*

I have very, very limited experience with coding and just want my site working, so if anyone can give me some super straightforward or step-by-step advice, that would be appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Install SEO plugin like Yoast SEO or All in one SEO Pack. I will suggest you to install Yoast SEO. https://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-seo/
Here you can edit Title, Description for each page specifically.

If you want to hide robots.txt just edit and put following code into your .htaccess file.

```
<Files robots.txt>
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from All
</Files>
```